# Running unit tests from Django libraries without manage.py

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm trying to write unit tests for a Python library that depends on Django. They work fine when I try to run them as part of a Django project:

```
>python manage.py test mexaminer.tests
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.006s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

When I try to run them on their own, this happens:

```
>python -m unittest mexaminer.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 38, in _set
up
    settings_module = os.environ[ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\os.py", line 631, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'
```

The same thing happens when I run `python -m django.utils.unittest mexaminer.tests`. Is there a way to run my unit tests without setting up a full Django project? Source code is [here](https://bitbucket.org/pieterdd/django-mexaminer/src/b7927793250c6a186b1ea53e7054c384a0ab627c/mexaminer/tests.py?at=unstable).

Comment: If your unit tests "depends" on a django project, then you are going to have to use `manage.py` when doing something on command line.

Comment: It has [some Django dependencies](https://bitbucket.org/pieterdd/django-mexaminer/src/b7927793250c6a186b1ea53e7054c384a0ab627c/mexaminer/tests.py?at=unstable), but nothing project-specific that I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are seeing this error because django can't figure out where is your settings file.

when you use `manage.py test` django set the path to the settings.

if you want to run your tests in a different environment you need to define a setup method that sets the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and creates test databases.

preferably you will create a tear down that removes the test database.

you can use [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/advanced/#using-the-django-test-runner-to-test-reusable-applications) to find out how to do so.